# SQL Injection Prevention in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, checkmarx

My Checkmarx report flags this method in my Spring Boot app as as a **High** severity **Second Order SQL Injection**:

```
public void updateEmployees(int storeId) {
  List<Employee> employees = employeeRepo.findByStoreId(storeId);
  employees.stream().forEach(e->{
    e.setActive('Y');
    employeeRepo.save(s);
  });
}
```

Per Checkmarx:

> ... The application constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the query without proper sanitization. The concatenated string is submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed accordingly.

The setActive(‘Y’) line appears to be the issue.

The guidance I find on data sanitization for Spring Data JPA usage suggests using a TypedQuery, created from an entityManager instance. Something like:

```
String jql = "from Employee where storeId = :storeId";
TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery(jql, Employee.class)
  .setParameter("storeId", storeId);
```

In my app, however, the EntityManager is implicitly created by Spring Boot.

So in order to implement "proper sanitization" here, do I need to explicitly create the EntityManager instance (to access its createQuery method)? Or is there a more straightforward way to implement this that does not requiree explicit EntityManager instantiation?

Comment: @Wooodchuck, Have you solved this issue?. I'm also getting same issue with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: @RaviKumarB, I concur with Stanislav below that this is a false positive. So my resolution was to switch off the Checkmarx preset that flags these. I've run into other of their presets, too, (e.g., Unsafe Object Binding) where Checkmarx flags issues in code that uses Spring which appear to be false positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a false positive, you need to contact the vendor and notify them about this case. When Hibernate generates SQL, it uses PreparedStatement. All the Entity fields that you change will be sent separately from the query - there won't be any concatenation.

Spring Data doesn't change the way Hibernate works with entities. So either this is a false positive, or you're looking at the wrong line of code.

Comment: Agreed, I see no SQL Injection in the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

JPA repository is against SQL injection you don't need to add intentionally. JPA features already avoid injection